# Generate out_filename from input_filename and suffix

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

I do a lot of steps of processing over an input_file. To avoid having to think of an output_filename at every step, I created the following name generation function:

```
def generate_out_file(in_file, suffix='out'):
    body_str = in_file.strip('./')
    flag = '.' in body_str
    _list = body_str.split('.')
    body_list = _list[:-1] if flag else [in_file]
    extension = _list[-1] if flag else 'txt'
    out_file = '.'.join(body_list + [suffix, extension])
    if in_file.startswith('./'):
        out_file = './' + out_file
    if in_file.startswith('../'):
        out_file = '../' + out_file
    return out_file
```

It looks very huge for me. Can you review my code and help me to improve it?

Comment: if we change first line to `body_str = os.path.basename(in_file)`, then last 4 lines can be replaces with `out_file = '/'.join([os.path.dirname(in_file), out_file])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dramatically simplify the function by using the [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead:

```
import os


def generate_out_file(in_file, suffix='out'):
    """Appends '.out' to an input filename."""
    filepath, file_extension = os.path.splitext(in_file)
    return filepath + "." + suffix + file_extension
```

Demo:

```
$ ipython3 -i test.py
In [1]: generate_out_file("./file.txt")  # file in a current directory
Out[1]: './file.out.txt'

In [2]: generate_out_file("/usr/lib/file.txt")  # path to a file
Out[2]: '/usr/lib/file.out.txt'

In [3]: generate_out_file("file.txt")  # just a file name
Out[3]: 'file.out.txt'

In [4]: generate_out_file("file")  # no extension
Out[4]: 'file.out'

In [5]: generate_out_file("/usr/lib/file")  # no extension with a path
Out[5]: '/usr/lib/file.out'
```